# How does Flickr's parallax scrolling work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

[Flickr's new design](http://www.flickr.com/) makes use of parallax scrolling on its section backgrounds. Parallax scrolling on retina displays is generally choppy (eg: http://inoviacapital.com/), but it is very smooth on Flickr.

**How does Flickr accomplish smooth parallax scrolling on retina displays?** I went through their source and found several parallax-related functions, but can't figure out *exactly* how they do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like they are using transforms instead of background-position as in your example.

Check out: http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html;

Comment: Interesting... I'll rewrite my current parallax functions to make use of transforms and see if that removes the jitter. Thanks! (I may try using Skrollr, https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr, as well.)